# how to obfuscate android library project step by step

Tags: android, android-library

I am facing a problem from long back to obfuscate android lib project not an android apps,
I am tried using android proguard GUI but after obfuscating i am unable to use the jar.

Please provide me the step step guide or any link where this issue already fixed.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

save this as proconf.txt and open with proguard gui as confiuration file and change input and output jar location .. and process 
also change locations of andoid.jar and support lib if required.

```
-injars 'bishwash/eclipse kepler'
-outjars bishwash/

-libraryjars bishwash/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-18/android.jar
-libraryjars 'bishwash/eclipse kepler/android-work/uxcam_lib_new/libs/android-support-v4.jar'

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-printmapping mapping.txt
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-dontpreverify
-verbose


-keepclassmembers class * extends java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Keep - Library. Keep all public and protected classes, fields, and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Keep names - _class method names. Keep all .class method names. This may be
# useful for libraries that will be obfuscated again with different obfuscators.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String,boolean);
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

Comment: The same process i already tried but the after obfuscating with specific class names the methods showing with blank when i checking using de-compiler. please provide me the more steps , my lib  having 7 to 8 package,any more info will be appreciated ...

Comment: try again with exact same proguard.txt as stated above. It's working for my project.

Comment: after doing the above steps, in side the method the logic is not obfuscating, the public methods i am exposing to end developer that logic need to be rename.....

Comment: I am keeping this option,   # Keep - Library. Keep all public and protected classes, fields, and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}   so what should be the keep option for renaming the logic inside the methods

Comment: is there any specific reason that few API are obfuscating to Byte code: others are not obfuscating.